# any free Cloud Services with networking tools?

Tags: linux, networking, open-source, free, static-ip-address

is there any online free cloud services that offer a static IP adress, and have a console where i can open a specific ports with linux application tools ( netcat, socat ,... ) ? thank you .

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to explore the capabilities on your own, I suppose. There are, however, a few free cloud storage options listed below.

Internxt Drive is a top contender in terms of privacy and security when it comes to free cloud storage. It gives you and your colleagues complete security to store a variety of files.

Sync.com is a cloud service that allows you to share files from anywhere on your computer or mobile phone. For storing and sharing private and sensitive data, Sync is the perfect solution
[Sync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCLBN.png)

Icedrive offers a cloud service that allows you to access, administer, and update your cloud storage with ease. It gives you a platform to share, present, and work with your files.

Mega Limited provides Mega, an online storage and file hosting service. The Windows, Mac, and Linux versions of Mega are all available.